# Not Exists With more than one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am in the process of writing a query that will read data in one table based on load date.  The main process will be to check to see if anything was added to the table from the most recent load date compared to the entire table's history.  The problem I come across is when using the 'Not Exists' statement for multiple columns. It checks to see if the specified columns exists individually rather than as a group of columns.  As Listed in the code below SQL is checking to see if last name, first name, and middle name doesn't exists between tables individually rather than all as one (almost like it is using an 'OR' rather than an 'AND' in the second query.  Any suggestions, or should I go another route?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        [Last Name] ,
        [First Name] ,
        [Middle Name]
INTO    #B
FROM    A
WHERE   Load_Date = ( SELECT    MAX(Load_Date)
                      FROM      A
                    )

SELECT DISTINCT
        [Last Name] ,
        [First Name] ,
        [Middle Name]
FROM    A
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [Last Name] ,
                            [First Name] ,
                            [Middle Name]
                     FROM   #B B
                     WHERE  A.[Last Name] = B.[Last Name]
                            AND A.[First Name] = B.[First Name]
                            AND A.[Middle Name] = B.[Middle Name] )
        AND Load_Date <> ( SELECT   MAX(Load_Date)
                           FROM     A
                         )
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` doesn't care what actually you're selecting, it only cares if there are rows returned. So practically you can change it to `SELECT NULL` and it will change nothing

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to get the name combinations that were not in the last load.  Here is a simpler way to do this:

```
Select [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name]
from A
group by [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name]
having max(Load_Date) < (Select Max(Load_Date) From A);
```

Your query should work.  I think you misunderstand how `not exists` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name]
FROM A
WHERE [Load_Date] = (SELECT MAX([Load_Date]) From A)
EXCEPT
SELECT [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name]
FROM A
WHERE [Load_Date] <> (SELECT MAX([Load_Date]) From A)
```